# Qt application unexpected LanguageChange event

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application which I want to have right-to-left layout direction. In main function I do set the layout direction to right-to-left and it is set correctly but before the window comes up a `QEvent::LanguageChange` is received and the layout direction is set to left-to-right. According to [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum)  this event is received when

> The application translation changed

but I don't have any in my app. This is a very big application and I have no idea where to look for what changes the language. My question is that is there any other thing that my cause LanguageChange event?

Comment: I recommend change system locale, region and language in windows preferences to Persian, and run again and see if left-to-right change happens again or not.

Comment: You can install an eventFilter to ignore this event

Comment: I propose you to first develop one very simple RTL Qt App to make sure that your implementation is correct and you are not missing anything in your code. Afterwards, when the proxy app works fine, try to do the same changes in your BIG app and find why such an event is passed to your App. Check this link as well: https://witekio.com/blog/qt-internationalization-arabic-chinese-right-left/

Comment: Thanks all for your comments I had tested every thing you may imagine and none of them helped. Finally I found the problem. it's in the answers.

Comment: which version of qt are you using ?

Comment: We are using Qt 5.12 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this was very surprising but finally we found the source of this problem. Our application has qml files some of which import older versions of controls. In some of files we had imported QtQuick.Controls 1.4. Replaced it with QtQuick.Controls 2.12 and problem solved!
though I don't know why it happened and what did controls have to do with setting app language but anyway it solved the problem.

Comment: You may be witnessing the symptoms of a deeper bug. You should review app + widget init code.

Comment: I can't really understand the source of this problem. I have tested it with a simpler app and didn't have this problem. I also have traced the program, all modules are initialized and the app is RTL but language change event is received right before the main window opens.